# How to generate all possible equations with a set of number and operators?

Tags: algorithms

I got a maths problem, for given that a set of character $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,*,/\}$. and then by using the set of characters to randomly generate 10 (or let say $N$) characters in an array, i.e. $[1,+,1,*,3,5,7,8,1]$. after that I need to find all the possibility of equations by using this array of characters plus 1 character '$=$'.

Therefore in this case, $[1,+,1,*,3,5,7,8,1]$
it would be like the following equations:

$1*1=1$ ,

$3+5=8$ ,

$7+1=3+5$ ,

$7+1=8$ ,

$8-1=7$ ,

$15=8+7$ ,

$15+3=18$
(maybe more)

it can form multiple digit operation, i.e $15+3=18$

so my question is I am trying using a program to generate the equations all. Could you guys give me some ideas what kind of algorithms can do so? or any methods do it? thanks a lot!

have a nice day!

Comment: Maybe best suited to [so]? Also just being picky, doesn't `8-1=7` and `7+=3+5` fall outside your inputs as you haven't a `-` or 2 `+`s? I like this question it got me to sign into [math.se]!

Comment: each equation should have valid operator. so any equations without operator cannot be accepted. 1=1 is not accepted.

Comment: just post it on stack overflow.... but always stupid and negative ppl just reply with some non sense and "minus" my question, i am getting sick with those pathetic ppl in there.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out aloud ;)

1. If you arranged the numbers in all possible ways noting you must have at least 2 numbers and incriminating to the maximum selected.
2. Then reproduce each number set with the `=` in each valid location. This would be your starting point.
3. Where you can then place the selected modifiers in each valid place.

   1. First one at a time.
   2. Then combining them one at a time.
4. Then for each iteration check the formulas validity saving or rejecting as required.

This seems quite lengthy but is a place to start. I think there will be some constraints or further optimisations I've not **YET** thought of you can apply to decrease the number of interactions you'll need to do.

I say *yet* as I'll not stop thinking about this. ;)

Comment: my approach is also similar like that. just like firstly pick 3 members in the array ,and these members must have an operator. then do all the combination. see if it is an equation. then pick 4 , do all combinations. and then until the length of arrays. but then i need a super computer